# Javascript Redirect after ASP.NET button postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to ask if we can do a javascript redirect after an ASP.NET button click event finishes.

The reason I ask this is I'm editing an ASP.NET page but do not have access to the source code, so I can only change the client side of things.

So in summary, I want to be able to still run the ASP.NET button event and after it finishes I need to redirect to another page.

I have look around and tested some but the ASP.NET postback is making the redirect in client-side not running.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 options :

1) at server side when the form submits  - do this :

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "blabla", "window.location='xxx'", true);
```

2) use hidden field and set value at submit ( at server side). when the page returns  , check its value via JS and do this :

```
if (document.getElementById('myHidden').value=='afterPostBack')
{
 window.location='xxx'
}
```

## edit

Before form submit - do this in JS

```
var form = document.getElementById("idOfForm");
form.onsubmit = function() {
  document.cookie="isRedirect=1; expires=Thu, 28 Nov 2013 02:23:26 GMT; path=/";
  this.submit();

}
```

and add the the bottom of the page this code :

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf('isRedirect=1')>-1)
{
 window.location='xxx'
}
```

Comment: As I said on my question, I cannot change anything on server side since I don't have any access to the source code (server side code / .cs file)

Comment: When I tried to add cookie, the cookie is still empty after that. Do you know why?

Comment: I did change the date, but the date I used is wrong apparently.. thanks for this..

Answer (score 1):

```
<head runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
   function PageRedirect() {
       window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/";
   }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<form runat="server">
```

// Use OnClientClick

```
     <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="PageRedirect(); return false;"/>
// Return False will not post the page even if its postback=true
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: But I would like to preserve the Button's server side event. What I would like to do is add a javascript function after the server side event to then redirect the page.

Comment: then you will be calling it like this way 
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(),"SomeName","PageRedirect();",true); 
In you server side code